# Numbered Headings in Org-Mode, Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I was wondering if you can get  automatic numbering  for headings in org-mode,something similar than the one used for simple lists. For example I can have this list:

1. one
2. two
3. three

And  I can reorder it to 
1. two
2. three
3. one

The list items change but the list numbers stay the same.  How can I do something similar with headings so that I can reorder the headings in a similar way.

- 1 One
- 2 Two
- 3 Three

To

- 1 Two
- 2 three
- 3 One

Comment: People are voting to close this particular question because this forum expects to see a classic programming question with sample code from the original poster that almost works and a request for help fixing a valiant effort by the original poster.  Almost no one participates on superuser for the Emacs tag, but that would be an ideal place for this question -- however, people down-vote questions over there because it is not an Emacs friendly place.  The best place for this type of question would be:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: As far as I am aware, the regexp for org headings expects a **star**, *not* a number at the outset.  Here is an example of `org-complex-heading-regexp`, the value for which can be obtained with `M-x describe-variable` in an `org-mode` buffer:  `"^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(TODO\\|DONE\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(\\[#.\\]\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)??\\(?:[  ]+\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)\\)?[  ]*$"`  Note the star at the beginning of the regexp.  That being said, you could superimpose an overlay to cover up the stars and display numbers on top, but this is likely more programming effort than what its worth.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know  there was an emacs specific site, which is great btw. Regarding the question  I know you have to use * at the beginning , I was wondering If I could get similar funcionality as the list, the number could be anywhere and In any format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to show this in Org itself, then I'm afraid this is not possible.  However you can do this easily in the exported document.  Look at the [exporting chapter](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings) in the manual.

You can provide an option like this: `#+options: num:2`.  Then all headlines at the 2nd level or above will be exported with a number.  You could then adjust the headlines as you wish in Org, without affecting the numbers in the exported document.

Comment: I can't do micro editing, but It should have no space after `num:`.

Answer (score 23):

Orgmode now has a built-in minor mode for this, contributed by Nicolas Goaziou.

Simply do [`M-x org-num-mode`](https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/org-num.el) to activate the display of dynamic headline numbering.

Comment: This must be accepted answer now.